# How do I remove the glass and change bulb from this lighting fixture?

Tags: light-fixture

I can't figure out how to unscrew or lift any of the three "nuts".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling one of the brass knobs laterally away from the glass.

Sometimes they are spring-loaded and you can pull them which allows you to drop one side of the glass and pull it out of the other two

Comment: also try unscrewing them if they do not pull.